# how to disable <input type="submit" ..... > when button is clicked

Tags: php, html

i'm a newbie with php and html. my code is creating button that depend on number of something and this is example of my code.

i have 2 php files, page1.php and page2.php

here is page1.php

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="page2.php">
    <?
    echo '<input type="submit" value="btn" name="btn"><br>';
    ?>
</form>
```

and this is page2.php

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
 {
    echo "clicked";
 }
 else
 {
    echo "no event";
 }
?>
```

what i want is when user click button. the button have to disable

and result should be "clicked" form echo in page2.php

the problem is i dont know how to disable that button and get result form page2

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem with all of the other answers so far is that when the submit button is disabled, it causes the `name`-`value` data pair associated with it to not be posted, since the button gets disabled before the data is posted. However, `submit` buttons are usually not used to pass data anyway, so one solution to this problem is to simply associate the data with a separate, hidden `input` element.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form" target="_blank" method="post" action="page2.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="btn" value="btn"></input>
      <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="btn">
      <br />
</form>
```

Notice that I added `id`s to the form and submit button for selection in JavaScript.

**JavaScript:**

```
// Get the form and the submit button.
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

// Disables the submit button.
function disableSubmitButton() {
  submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', '')
}

// Disable the submit button when the form is submitted, with fallback for IE 5-8.
if (form.addEventListener) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', disableSubmitButton, false);
} else {
  form.attachEvent('onsubmit', disableSubmitButton);
}
```

If you had two different submit buttons, you could also pass a different value to the action page depending on which button was pressed by setting the value of the hidden `input` element based on which one was pressed:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form" target="_blank" method="post" action="page2.php">
  <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="button-pressed" value=""></input>
  <input id="submit-button-1" type="submit" value="Submit Button 1">
  <input id="submit-button-2" type="submit" value="Submit Button 2">
  <br />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Get the form and the hidden input.
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hidden-input');

// Set the value of the hidden input depending on which button was pressed.
function setHiddenInputValue(event) {
  // Get the id of the button that was pressed.
  pressedButtonId = event.target.id;

  // Set the value of the hidden input element to be the same as the id of the pressed button.
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', pressedButtonId);

// Disables the submit button that was pressed.
function disableSubmitButton(event) {
  event.target.setAttribute('disabled', '')
}

// Disable the submit button when the form is submitted, with fallback for IE 5-8.
if (form.addEventListener) {
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    // Event object fallback for IE 5-8.
    if (!event) {
      event = window.event;
    }

    setHiddenInputValue(event);
    disableSubmitButton(event);
  }, false);
} else {
  form.attachEvent('onsubmit', function(event) {
    // Event object fallback for IE 5-8.
    if (!event) {
      event = window.event;
    }

    setHiddenInputValue(event);
    disableSubmitButton(event);
  });
}
```

Comment: I got your point and thanks a lot. But if I have 2 or more button all value form hidden will pass to another file right? (create hidden that depend on number of button ) EDIT : another file It mean page2.php

Comment: @Joe9619 Are you asking how you could pass two different values depending on which button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, Now i'm trying to use javascript function to create hidden elements in each button . But I'm not sure that's a good idea and sorry for my english skill.

Comment: So you have two submit buttons, and you want to pass a different value depending on which one of them is pressed? Or are there more than two buttons?

Comment: On my project I have a many button but now I want to make a simple with 2 button first.

Comment: @Joe9619 I've updated my answer with a potential approach for dealing with multiple buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable when form submit :-

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: I want to use $_POST["btn"] at page2.php too. this script can disable submit button but cant use variable "btn" at page2.php  and if I use echo $_POST["btn"] that give me a result UNDEFINE variable "btn" . anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using jQuery. You need to include the jQuery script. And write your own code for manipulating the events

```
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="page2.php">
    <?
    echo '<input type="submit" value="btn" name="btn" id="submitBtn"><br>';
    ?>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").attr('disabled','disabled'); // disable the button

   // $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled') You can enable the button from this code
});

});
```

Comment: variable $_POST['btn'] not define at page2.php  i think variable name="btn" cant pass through page1 to page2. but thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form target="_blank" method="post" action="page2.php">
   <input type="submit" value="btn" name="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for help but page2.php can't find variable "btn"